# JNI, самый быстрый способ каста byte[] to int[] наоборот

Tags: java, jni, unsafe

Всем доброго времени суток!

Задача такая: есть массив **byte[]**, полученный по сети. На самом деле в этих байтах содержится массив **int[]** того же размера, вчетверо меньшего количества. Нужно просто взять область памяти и подменить указатель, переписав служебную информацию о массиве (длина и т.п.). Массивы сравнительно большие ~100кб. Массивов много и критически важно обрабатывать их быстро.

Испробованные решения и скорости (с разогревом JIT):

1. Обход в цикле и сбор int через битовые операции (был отброшен сразу из-за неэффективности)
2. Использование ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[]).asIntBuffer().get(int[]) время: 49200 наносекунд
3. Использование JNI и GetByteArrayRegion/SetIntArrayRegion время: 14700 наносекунд
4. Unsafe closed API время: в среднем около 200 наносекунд

В результате изысканий выяснилось, что самый интересный вариант - каст через Unsafe closed API, однако есть некие проблемы связанные то ли с кэшированием, то ли с тем, что я не всю информацию правильно в header массивов пишу. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, если кто знает, или у кого есть желание =)

```
public class UnsafeUtil {

    public static Unsafe unsafe;
    private static final long INT_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET;
    private static final long BYTE_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET;
    private static final long ADDRESS_SIZE;
    private static final long ARRAY_TYPE_OFFSET;
    private static final long ARRAY_LENGTH_OFFSET;
    private static final int ARRAY_TYPE_INTS;
    private static final int ARRAY_TYPE_BYTES;
    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH_INTS = 32768;
    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH_BYTES = ARRAY_LENGTH_INTS<<2;
    private static final long ARRAY_HEADER_INTS;
    private static final long ARRAY_HEADER_BYTES;


    private static int[] test;


    private static UnsafeUtil instance = new UnsafeUtil();

    static {
        try {
            Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe)f.get(null);
            int[] ints = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH_INTS];
            byte[] bytes = new byte[ARRAY_LENGTH_BYTES];
            ADDRESS_SIZE = unsafe.addressSize();
            BYTE_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(ints.getClass());
            INT_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(bytes.getClass());
            System.err.println("INFO: Initialized binary caster.");
            System.err.println("INFO: address size " + ADDRESS_SIZE);
            System.err.println("INFO: offset int[] " + INT_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET);
            System.err.println("INFO: offset byte[] " + BYTE_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET);
            if (BYTE_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET != INT_ARRAY_HEADER_OFFSET){
                System.err.println("CRITICAL ERROR: Sorry, i don't know your environment. It seems" +
                        " like you are using something rare (int[] offset != byte[] offset, i dont know" +
                        "how to cast it fast in binary level.)");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            // searching length offset
            ARRAY_TYPE_OFFSET = ADDRESS_SIZE;
            ARRAY_LENGTH_OFFSET = ADDRESS_SIZE + 4L;
            ARRAY_TYPE_BYTES = unsafe.getInt(bytes, ARRAY_TYPE_OFFSET);
            ARRAY_TYPE_INTS = unsafe.getInt(ints, ARRAY_TYPE_OFFSET);
            ARRAY_HEADER_BYTES = unsafe.getLong(bytes, ADDRESS_SIZE);
            ARRAY_HEADER_INTS = unsafe.getLong(ints, ADDRESS_SIZE);
            // warming-up
            long l = 0L;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                l+= testReinterpretBtI();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
                l+= testReinterpretItB();
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            l+= testReinterpretBtI();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            l+= testReinterpretItB();
        }
        System.err.println("AVG CAST TIME WITH WARM-UP: " + (l/20) + " ns");
    }


    public static byte[] modifyArrayLength(byte[] array, int newLength, long lengthOffset){
        unsafe.putInt(array, lengthOffset, newLength);
        return array;
    }

    public static int[] reinterpretAsIntArray(byte[] array){
        unsafe.putLong(array, ADDRESS_SIZE, ARRAY_HEADER_INTS);
        Object o = array;
        return (int[]) o;
    }

    public static byte[] reinterpretAsByteArray(int[] array){
        unsafe.putLong(array, ADDRESS_SIZE, ARRAY_HEADER_BYTES);
        Object o = array;
        return (byte[]) o;
    }


    private static long testReinterpretBtI(){
        byte[] b = new byte[ARRAY_LENGTH_BYTES];
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        int[] i = reinterpretAsIntArray(b);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        test = i;
        return (t2-t1);
    }

    private static long testReinterpretItB(){
        int[] i = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH_INTS];
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        byte[] b = reinterpretAsByteArray(i);
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        test = i;
        return (t2-t1);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: 
Удалось выяснить примерно куда копать и в чём проблема. Вероятно я при вызове unsafe я затирал счётчик ссылок объекта и в какой-то момент объект удалялся сборщиком мусора, что приводило потом к access violation при попытке обратиться к уже освобождённой памяти. буду думать о том, как организовать стек обмена, чтобы с ссылками косяков не было. наверное вручную считать буду, или сделаю +1 к счётчику и буду те же самые объекты переиспользовать, или off-heap array. Предположительно последнее - самое лучшее.

UPDATE (Уточнение):
Есть очередь Dequeue из массивов byte[] фиксированного размера. Массивы byte[] из очереди используются как буферы для получения данных по сети, чтобы не делать memalloc. в буферы из очереди помещаются данные byte[], приходящие от сервера клиенту. Клиент кастует данные буфера byte[] в массив int[] , использует для своих целей. каст происходит через unsafe как описано в коде выше. когда массивы int[] больше не нужны, они снова кастуются в byte[] и отправляются обратно в очередь. в какой-то момент (похоже, после прохода gc) случается accessViolation при попытке обращения к int[]

Comment: Может быть (int) byte

Comment: Сергей, обход в цикле выглядит заведомо более медленным. Если делать каст (int) byte для каждого отдельного значения в java - коде, то кроме медленной скорости, ещё и некорректный массив получится, т.к. одно число int закодировано в 4 байтах. можно int собрать из 4 байт битовыми сдвигами, но это жутко неэффективно, см. мой пункт 1

Comment: может я что-то не понял, но в С это можно сделать так (byte == char поэтому UB не будет) `char * arr = ...; return (int *)arr ;`

Comment: Тут, насколько я понимаю, основная проблема не со стороны C++, а именно в том, как из Java-кода JVM передаёт данные в C++ код и обратно. Вместо стандартных C-шных указателей передаются и возвращаются особые указатели на Java-объекты массива и с ними из-за этого приходится работать с учётом особенностей JNI. В норме данные при вызове копируются. Соответственно лишние memoryAllocation, хотелось бы этого избежать..

Comment: Да, и вот в доках всё подробно и понятно про Critical: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html . Вот тут сравнения и информация для понимания: https://habrahabr.ru/post/222997/ . И ещё кучу инфы нашёл при первом же запросе в Google.

Comment: Оба этих мануала я уже знаю практически наизусть. То, что требуется сделать - более тонко. Расширю вопрос примерами кода на с++.

Comment: Apache Commons IO IOUtils очень быстро конвертирует. пробуй эту библиотеку

Comment: Не то http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840190/java-convert-4-bytes-to-int ?

Comment: А зачем `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[]).asIntBuffer().get(int[])`? он же копирует один массив в другой. .get(int[]) - This method transfers ints from this buffer into the given destination array. Прямо с intbuffer-ом работать нельзя? И почему бы сразу не получать int[]?

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев писал про вариант использования Critical подхода. Скажите, почему он не применим в Вашей ситуации? И что означает: _более тонко_?

Answer (score 5):

Хм, а что насчёт того, чтобы парсить данные принимаемые по сети сразу в int? Потребуется низкоуровневая реализация, правда. Но может не подойти, ибо не знаю, каким образом вы их получаете.

Comment: Идея концептуально хорошая. Данные получаю в виде byte[] от ZeroMq - это OpenSource библиотека обмена сообщениями, если не получится с кастами сделать, тогда нагло перекомпилирую ZeroMq под себя =) Но это посложнее задача будет наверное.

Comment: @Radiance Меня зацепил ваш вопрос, всё ещё о нём думаю, и вот что пришло в голову. А что, если использовать какие-то инструменты для манипуляции байт-кодом? То есть, байт-кодные библиотеки. Пакет Sun Unsafe, кажется, может предоставить такие функции. Точно не знаю, ибо я пользовался только инструментами для доступа к финализированным и приватным полям, но слышал, что там есть инструменты для сложного каста переменных.

Comment: Спасибо за интересную информацию! попробую покопаться в библиотеке, по результатам отпишусь тут. Я вообще был сильно удивлён, когда стал исследовать данную задачу и не обнаружил простого и быстрого решения.

Comment: Удалось сделать. И даже работает, НО: похоже, что при частом обращении к массиву что-то уходит в регистры процессора/кэш и из-за того, что там другой размер сдвига/размер массива содержится (для старого типа массива) случается access violation. Буду думать в сторону sinchronized и volatile, чтобы запретить кэширование в регистры. Текущая реализация выше в вопросе.

Answer (score 4):

Попробовал запустить Ваш код и на тестовом примере получил почти верный результат, только порядок байт в `int` не такой как в массиве.

У меня в массиве байты идут:

```
0-й элемент массива
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
1-й элемент массива
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
2-й элемент массива
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
3-й элемент массива
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

То есть в `int`е я хочу получить

```
1й байт  2й байт  3й байт  4й байт
00011111 00010101 01010101 00001111
```

а получаю

```
4й байт  3й байт  2й байт  1й байт
00001111 01010101 00010101 00011111
```

если у вас проблема с этим же, то можно решить, например перестановкой элементов в массиве наподобие:

```
void rotate(byte[] arr){
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i+=4){
            byte tmp = arr[i], tmp1 = arr[i+1];
            arr[i] = arr[i+3];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i+2];
            arr[i+2] = tmp1;
            arr[i+3] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

по времени накладные расходы в пределах 200 наносекунд, т.е. весь процесс конвертирования в пределах 400 наносекунд.

Comment: Порядок байт определяется при маршаллинге моим же сервером, так что это не критично (упаковываю я в том же порядке как и распаковываю)

Comment: Кроме того, удалось выяснить примерно куда копать и в чём проблема. Вероятно я при вызове unsafe затирал счётчик ссылок объекта и в какой-то момент объект удалялся сборщиком мусора, что приводило потом к access violation при попытке обратиться к уже освобождённой памяти. буду думать о том, как организовать стек обмена, чтобы с ссылками косяков не было. наверное вручную считать буду, или сделаю +1 к счётчику и буду те же самые объекты переиспользовать. или off-heap array.

Comment: @Radiance, тогда не из вопроса не понятно какие проблемы у Вас возникают. Опишите пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: Есть очередь Dequeue<Object> из массивов byte[] фиксированного размера. Массивы byte[] из очереди используются как буферы для получения данных по сети, чтобы не делать memalloc. в буферы из очереди помещаются данные byte[], приходящие от сервера клиенту. Клиент кастует данные буфера byte[] в массив int[] , использует для своих целей. каст происходит через unsafe как описано в коде выше. когда массивы int[] больше не нужны, они снова кастуются в byte[] и отправляются обратно в очередь. в какой-то момент (похоже, после прохода gc) случается accessViolation при попытке обращения к int[].

Answer (score -5):

А если сделать вот так (сам не проверял только предположение).

```
byte[] byte = getDataFromServer();
int[] int = new int[];

for(int i =0; i<byte.length(); i++){
    Byte curr = new Byte(byte[i]); //casting to type
    int[i] = curr.intValue();
}
```

Я же правильно понял что в каждом байте находится какая то цифра типа `int`?

Comment: нет, int содержится в четырёх смежных байтах. кроме того, как я писал выше, обход в цикле - заведомо медленное решение.