# Чтение массива чисел

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Есть `InputStream` в котором записана последовательность известной длины 32 битных чисел в **LittleEndian** порядке байт.

Вопрос, как наиболее эффективно эту последовательность считать в массив? Сейчас делаю так

```
public int[] read(InputStream strm, int count) throws IOException {
    int[] res = new int[count];
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byte[] arr = buffer.array();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strm.read(arr, 0, 4) < 4)
            throw new IOException("Stream read error");
        res[i] = buffer.getInt(0);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Но хотелось бы как-то так

```
public int[] read(InputStream strm, int count) throws IOException {
    int[] res = new int[count];
    int size = count * 4;
    if (strm.read((byte[])res, 0, size) < size)
        throw new IOException("Stream read error");
    return res;
}
```

Т.е. одним чтением сразу считать весь массив.

Пробовал так

```
public int[] readArray(InputStream strm, int count) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * count);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byte[] arr = buffer.array();
    if (strm.read(arr) < arr.length)
        throw new IOException("Stream read error");
    IntBuffer res = buffer.asIntBuffer();
    return res.array();
}
```

Но на `return res.array();` вылетает `UnsupportedOperationException`

Если работать с `IntBuffer`

```
IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(4 * count);
```

то у него невозможно поменять порядок байт

Вот такой вариант

```
public int[] readArray(InputStream strm, int count) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * count);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byte[] arr = buffer.array();
    if (strm.read(arr) < arr.length)
        throw new IOException("Stream read error");
    IntBuffer intBuffer = buffer.asIntBuffer();
    int[] res = new int[count];
    intBuffer.get(res);
    return res;
}
```

позволяет считать за одну операцию, но за счет двойного потребления памяти. Тоже не комильфо.

Comment: есть вот такое безумие https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569983/